# Error in SQL Server to WCF development

Tags: sql-server, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-data-services

I am testing a DB that have two tables (Satellite and Channel) to be exposed as I need using WCF. fortunately, I tried everything I know and online for more that I week now and I can't solve the problem.

This is the service contract `IService.cs`

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Satalite> SelectSatalite(int satNum);

    [OperationContract]
    List<Satalite> SataliteList();

    [OperationContract]
    List<Channel> ChannelList(int satNum);

    [OperationContract]
    String Sat(int satNum);

}
```

And this is the `Service.svc.cs` file

```
public class Service : IService
{
   DataDbDataContext DbObj = new DataDbDataContext();

   public List<Satalite> SataliteList()
   {
        var satList = from r in DbObj.Satalites
                      select r;

        return satList.ToList();
   }

    public List<Satalite> SelectSatalite(int satNum)
    {
        var satList = from r in DbObj.Satalites
                      where r.SateliteID == satNum
                      select r;

        return satList.ToList();
    }

    public List<Channel> ChannelList(int satNum)
    {
        var channels = from r in DbObj.Channels
                       where r.SateliteID == satNum
                       select r;

        return channels.ToList();
    }


    public String Sat(int satNum)
    {
        Satalite satObj = new Satalite();

        satObj = DbObj.Satalites.Single(p => p.SateliteID == satNum);
        return satObj.Name;
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the first three I got an error when testing them using `wcftestclient.exe`, the last one works with no issues.

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at IService.SelectSatalite(Int32 satNum)
>   at ServiceClient.SelectSatalite(Int32 satNum)
>
> Inner Exception: The underlying connection was closed: The connection
>   was closed unexpectedly.
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

What I understand is that the error happens for the custom classes which are the DB tables, if I used a known type by the .net compiler (ex. `int` or `string`) it will work with no problems. Fortunately, I didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error appears to be one of two reasons:

1. a **timeout** since you're returning too much data, e.g. the selection of the data from the database takes too long for the service method to complete in time

   **or:**
2. the message size is **too large**, because you're selecting too much data, and thus the WCF communication aborts before the whole data has been returned

My solution:

- **don't select** all data from the tables! Return only as much data as you can really handle / display, e.g. 10 rows, 20 rows or a maximum of 100 rows....

Try this - if you change your method to:

```
 public List<Satalite> SataliteList(int count)
 {
      var satList = (from r in DbObj.Satalites
                    select r).Take(count);

      return satList.ToList();
 }
```

Can you call this from the WCF Test Client with e.g. `count = 10` or `count = 50` ??

Comment: Thanks for the respond, I am with you that I am returning too much data (you are talking about 8 to 12 columns each !!) but my program requires it. So, I am asking is there a way that I can extend the time for it not to reach a timeout or increase the size of the message because I need that !?!. Also, I tested your idea of selecting some rows at a time, but I am still having an error, even with count = 1!!!.

Comment: @darking050: yes, of course you can increase the timeout, and the size of the allowable messages - but that's just "band aids" on top of the real problem - why do you need to transmit this much data?? Maybe you should use a different approach than transmitting that over a service, if it's this much data....

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting timeout settings on server and client side will help you.

Server Side adjust the **SendTimeout** attribute of binding element and on client side adjust the **RecieveTimeout** attribute of binding element.

Thanks,